# Google Maps automatically sets Position:relative of #map div

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I have a strange problem or at least to me its kinda strange. When i style my #map div and set the position:fixed (since i need it as a background) it automatically sets the position to relative and overrides my settings. I couldnt figure out where to change this behavior.

The parent class:

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
}
```

and the #map

```
 #map {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100vw;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 0;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: fixed;
```

code is simple:

```
<div class="wrapper">
       <div id="map"></div>
        <div class="entries container">
            {% with 940 as width %}{% placeholder content %}{% endwith %}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now when i enter the page it first renders nicely and after a milisec the apply of the js i assume the #map div got these lines added

```
element.style {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

well if i change it manually it does exactly what i want it to but i cant disable this override. Has anyone else expierienced something like this? Im kinda stuck.

Im usign Chrome.

Thanks in advance for your time!
Regards

JS file:

```
var map; 
function initialize() {
    var v = {lat: 4.00, lng: 7.00};

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: v,
        map: map,
        title: 'V!'
    });

    var styleArray = [
        {
            "featureType": "all",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "hue": "#ff0000"
                },
                {
                    "saturation": -100
                },
                {
                    "lightness": -30
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "all",
            "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#ffffff"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "all",
            "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#353535"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "landscape",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#656565"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#505050"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#808080"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "#454545"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.295065, 7.937821),
        zoom: 14,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
        },
        disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        draggable: false,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        overviewMapControlOptions: {
            opened: false,
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: styleArray
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);

    var locations = [
        ['V', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 4.0, 7.0, 'https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/hollow-pin-red.png']
    ];
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        if (locations[i][1] == 'undefined') {
            description = '';
        } else {
            description = locations[i][1];
        }
        if (locations[i][2] == 'undefined') {
            telephone = '';
        } else {
            telephone = locations[i][2];
        }
        if (locations[i][3] == 'undefined') {
            email = '';
        } else {
            email = locations[i][3];
        }
        if (locations[i][4] == 'undefined') {
            web = '';
        } else {
            web = locations[i][4];
        }
        if (locations[i][7] == 'undefined') {
            markericon = '';
        } else {
            markericon = locations[i][7];
        }
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: markericon,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][5], locations[i][6]),
            map: map,
            title: locations[i][0],
            desc: description,
            tel: telephone,
            email: email,
            web: web
        });
        link = '';
    }

    map.panBy(0, 200);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function () {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(center);

});
```

Comment: I've had the same trouble, then I fixed it just using:

#map {
      position: unset !important;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding in the !important to the `position:fixed`property. If that does not work then add jquery to set the position to fixed at the bottom of the js file right after the `map.panBy(0,200)` and also after the `map.setCenter(center);`

```
$("#map").css("position","fixed !important");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: !important did the Trick! Thank you so much! Should have tried this instead of searching in files for hours!

Comment: I came across this same issue when troubleshooting a shortened map on an iPhone 6 (11.2.2).  The bottom 20pixels of the map were pushed up - like a margin on the bottom...its due to the google map JS adding `overflow:hidden` to the actual in-line DIV.  The above tip adding `!important` did the trick for me too.  As far as I can tell it doesn't impact the view on any other device (I will report back if it does)

Answer (score 9):

Same situation happened in my case when using Google Map API and showing map using jQuery. In my case I fixed using CSS as follows:

```
#map
{
    position: fixed !important; 
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

The div element to show map is as follows:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: This did the trick for me.  It seems like google map injects `position: relative` and `overflow: hidden` while adding the map inside the wrapper. So, even if you add some inline styling inside the container wrapping the map, it gets over-written. The solution is to create a separate CSS file and link it to the HTML file.

Comment: I don't believe `!important` is ever a fix. This suggests that there is an upstream issue with the Google maps API and it's outputting incorrect styles.